# SSIS Exporting from one DB to another using parameters in the destination

Tags: import, ssis

I have data on table T1 in database DB1.

I need move to the table T2 in database DB2 only those rows of T1 that have Field F1 equals to certain values.

These values are on a table TC in database DB2. DB1 cannot refer to DB2 therefore in the DataFlow Component of my dtsx I cannot write a query with a join between T1 and TC.

I see two possible paths:

1. I could first import all the rows from T1 then filter them in the dtsx before pouring them in T2
2. Instead of having a SQL query to get the data from DB1 I could write a stored procedure in DB1 that accepts a table valued parameter and then I could try (I don't know how) to put my parameters (1,2,4 in the example) in the TVP and invoke the stored procedure with this.

I have to do this kind of import for dozens of tables therefore solution 2 seems really too convoluted and complicated. Solution 1 seems to do too much useless work, first importing everything and then discarding part of what was imported.

Is there a best practice or smart trick in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a merge join to join data from T1 and Tc on field F1. So two data source, one for T1, one for TC. No parameters are applied yet. You need to use a sort component to sort on the join field (F1) in both result sets for the merge join to work. Then define a join type (inner) in merge join component. This is where the parameters from TC are applied to T1, so you use a inner join to apply the parameters. Finally export the result to T2.

[image]

Another way is just import everything from T1 to a temp table on DB2, call it T2_temp, then you can use a query to join T2_temp with TC on F1, then insert the result to T2.

Comment: Thankx for your suggestion It seems basically what i wanted to do in my solution number 1. What makes me suspiucious is that a lot of data are first loaded and then discarded. Unless... i would like to know if in your solution the bulk of the data travels from DB1 to DB2 or is it first filtered? I still don't know the final architecture but say the SSIS server is on a third physical machine (SRV3). Suppose also that applying the filter removes the vast majority of the data.

Comment: [continued] Of course i want the least amount of data travel from one server to the other.@thotwielder: Is your solution moving ALL data from DB1 to SRV3 and then only the few filtered one to DB2? Or is the filtering also preventing the bulk of data to go from DB1 to SRV3? thx

Comment: The data filtering is in the merge join, so it is happening where your ssis is running, not on DB2 (if DB2 and SSIS are not running on the same server). So DB2 only receives the final result set. The filtering (merge join) must be happening somewhere, so in your case it's on SRV3, where ssis is running.

Comment: How big is your data (T1)? Optimally, you can do the sort in the query in T1 and TC, and specify the data sources as sorted in advanced editor(will give more detail if needed), so you don't need the sort components, which are slow and uses more resource. This way the data from both source can begin the merge join immediately when the sources begin to output data (queries are running) and don't have to wait until all data are generated (queries finish). So it's very efficient both in time and resource. And all these happen on your SRV3.

Comment: Thankx again for your time. T1 can be anything from 10K to 10M, it depends. T2 would be estremely small, surely less than 10 ... it's just a collection of filter values. Basically, in the dtsx i have a SLECT * FROM T1.MyTable MT WHERE MT.MyParameter IN (at_value1, at_value2, at_value4). If it were always just one value, I would be passing a parameter to the data flow. BUT, the values can be in an unspecified quantity.The best would be being able to write the data flow query in such a way that it accepts a variable number of parameters.Maybe with Dinamic SQL?Would that be bad,performance-wise?

Comment: you don't need to pass any parameter to T1 query, in T1 it's simply: SLECT * FROM T1.MyTable MT, in TC: select distinct somefield from TC. you then join the result set from T1 to the result set from TC in the merge join component. In merge join it's doing something similar to this query (although it's actually something different because it's not sql ): SLECT T1.* FROM T1 join TC ON T1.F1  = TC.F1, this equals to  your original query.

Comment: Depending on how many columns you retrieve from T1, merge join may or may not have performance issue. you need to try that to find out.